# IIS URL 301 redirect url with query string to extentionless

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewrite-module

I want to 301 redirect this url:

`Index.asp?SourceID=20&CategoryID=20&ArticleID=1`

to:
Contact

in IIS -> URL REWRITE I have this set up:

```
**Match URL**
Requested URL:  Matches the Pattern
Using: Exact Match
Pattern: Index.asp?SourceID=20&CategoryID=20&ArticleID=1
```

**Action**

```
Action type: Redirect
Redirect URL: http://www.mydomian.com/Contact
Append query string: TRUE
Redirect type: Permanent (301)
```

When I test it I get a 404.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at URL Rewrite, here there is a blog post that has something similar where you could use a Rewrite Map to have those declared in web.config:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx

Comment: as I am not so knowledgeable in this area, cloud anyone  be so kind as to write here a "how to"? how can I redirect (301) this: Index.asp?SourceID=20&CategoryID=20&ArticleID=1  , to: Contact?